# Using CSS3 keyframes to animate divs sliding, but divs pushing other div

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I am making a sliding nav bar without the use of JavaScript.

Everything is working great except one thing: When the divs get to their final position (at 100% of the keyframe,) the left div pushes the top div to the bottom of the document.

I have tried position: absolute, but that was to no avail. I tried Having left div's width set to 6% and the top divs width set to 94%, but when the user shrinks his or her browser it breaks instantly.

HTML:

```
<div id="left_bar"><p>This is sparta!</p></div>
<div class="top_bar">This is not Sparta!</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* LEFT SIDEBAR*/
#left_bar {
-webkit-animation:myFirst 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
font-size: .2px;
padding-left: 5px;
float: left
}


/* LEFT SIDEBAR ANIMATION*/
@-webkit-keyframes myFirst /* Safari and Chrome */{
    0% {
        background: orange;
        width: 6%;
        height: 0px;
        margin-top: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        background:orange;
        width: 6%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.7;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
/* TOP SIDEBAR*/
.top_bar {
background-color: black;
-webkit-animation:mySecond 3s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
float: right;
}

/* TOP SIDEBAR ANIMATION*/
@-webkit-keyframes mySecond /* Safari and Chrome */{
    0% {
        background: orange;
        width: 0%;
        height: 8%;

    }
    100% {
        background:orange;
        width: 94%;
        height: 8%;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qebp/) NOTE: jsFiddle is making it look entirely different. the left sidebar does not take up 100% of the height, but when the top sidebar takes up 94% of the page, it shows the top bar jump underneath the left sidebar.

Comment: Just been playing around with the fiddle if i add positon: fixed; and top: 0; to top bar it doesnt move down at the end. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that you have `padding-left:5px;` on `#left_bar`. Remove it and [**your problem is fixed**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qebp/3/)

An alternate sufficient solution would be to use `calc` to shorten with width of one of them by the same amount

```
@-webkit-keyframes mySecond {
    ...
    100% {
        width: calc(94% - 5px);
        ...
    }
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qebp/2/)

Comment: I don't believe I have any borders on anything, but thank you for your input. +1 for the css calc(). I had no idea you could do that with CSS, and that will prove incredibly useful in the future. @Zeaklous

Comment: @PixelReaper Yeah, sorry, I rushed my answer. I updated it with the correct solution

Comment: Question: When I do the calc() feature, it takes the space off the right side, not the left. How do I tell it to take off the length from the left side? @Zeaklous

Comment: @PixelReaper You can't using your current setup. To do so you'd have to give it `position:absolute` or `fixed`, give it `right:0px` (using `right` to animate it), and change your animations to compensate for that change. But as I said in the updated answer, your issue is the padding you added. If you still want that space in between I would keep the width using the same calc function I have but give `.top_bar` `margin-right:5px`

Comment: Oops-didn't mean to take away the answer thing.. I already changed it to accommodate for that.. Thank you for getting back to me though @Zeaklous