# Animate closing side panel on right side

Tags: css, css-animations

So I got my right sidebar animating nicely coming in, but how would I animate out as of right now it just closing without any animation?

```
.calendarQuickpanelContainer {
    animation: animateopen 0.6s;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 462px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.calendarQuickpanel {
    display: block;
}

@keyframes animateopen {
    0% {
      right: -462px;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      right: 0;
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using CSS3 keyframes to animate divs sliding, but divs pushing other div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862633/using-css3-keyframes-to-animate-divs-sliding-but-divs-pushing-other-div)

Comment: @amirify this is just showing how to open it. I have solved that. It’s closing I want to animate

Comment: please add your html and javascript code. This way I can help you better.

Answer (score -1):

Animation is not very good, better use transition here. You have better control because you can use a class to toggle states.

```js
function toggleFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("sidebar");
  element.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
#sidebar {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-260px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

button {
  float: right;
  margin: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
<button onclick="toggleFunction()">toggle sidebar</button>
```